# View new count column

Tags: sql, count, sql-view

I have 2 tables. One who is like a transactional table

```
userId  category
```

Second table also has

```
userId (as primary key) 
and other columns (not important)
```

I wanted to create a view based on these 2 tables. Also, I want to have one column which puts into the cells the count from the transactional table who has the same id and eventually matches a special categorie f.e "car".

I thought of maybe using nested select statement, but since i'm a beginner i'm a little bit confused.

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this.

```
select count(b.userId) as ID, b.category from table2 a inner join transactional b 
on a.userId = b.userId where b.category= 'car' group by b.category;
```